# RollingPitTabBar background problem - Swift

Tags: swift

I am using RollingPitTabBar pod. As you can see in the photo, there is a white background behind the tab. How can I remove this background? Let the background look white and match that view in color. So, I want the transparency of the background in RollingPitTabBar.

[image]

Comment: Checking the pod's GitHub I see that the bar appears to have a property `.barBackColor` ("Bar Back Color" in the Inspector). Verify that it is set to a clear color. You can also use `Debug\View Debugging\Capture View Hierarchy` to check if there is a runtime layout issue causing that white area (such as the content view not actually extending below the bar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced this situation. Add this to your `RollingPitTabBar` at `storyboard` :

[image]

Hope it helps...

Comment: Can you increase Tabbar's rolling speed? I am trying but not working.